# Passing values between views MVC5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating an event management system and I want to create an event and then create multiple tickets for this event. I am using c# and ASP.NET MVC. I have created these model classes;

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Location { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public String Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int TicketsAvailable { get; set; }
    //navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }
    //navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Ticket { get; set;}
 }

  public class Ticket
{
   public int TicketID { get; set; }
   [Required]
   [ForeignKey("Event")]
   //foreign key
    public int EventID { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public string Description { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public float Price { get; set; }       
    //navigation property
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
    //navigation property
    public ICollection<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

I have used the Scaffolded CRUD views for the events and then I want to pass the EventID for the event I create to the AddTicket view and create new tickets specific to the event.
Here is my controller class;

```
public class Events1Controller : Controller
{
    private IEventRepository _eventRepository;
    private ITicketRepository _ticketRepository;

    public Events1Controller()
    {
    this._eventRepository = new EventRepository(new ApplicationDbContext());
    this._ticketRepository = new TicketRepository(new ApplicationDbContext());
    }

    // GET: Events
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View(_eventRepository.GetEvents());
    }
// GET: Events/Create
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Events/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific  properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "EventID,Name,Location,Date,Description,TicketsAvailable")] Event @event)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Session["Event1"] = @event;
            _eventRepository.InsertEvent(@event);

            return RedirectToAction("SaveTickets");
        }

        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SaveTickets()
    {           
        Event @e1 = Session["Event1"] as Event;
        Ticket @ticket1 = new Ticket
        {
            EventID = @e1.EventID
        };

        return View(@ticket1);

    }



 // POST: Events/AddToTickets
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult AddToTickets([Bind(Include = "TicketID, EventID,    Description, Price")] Ticket @ticket)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _ticketRepository.InsertTicket(@ticket);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }




<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Event</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TicketID)


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EventID, htmlAttributes: new { @class    = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EventID, new { htmlAttributes =   new { @class = "form-control" } })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price,"",  new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="AddToTickets" class="btn btn-default" />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")

</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I have used forms within my razor views and the events are saving to the database correctly, and the EventID is being set in the Ticket and passed to the SaveTicket view. However the problem occurs when I try and save the ticket, the ticket does not save and the page simply refreshes. I have tried many tutorial but none have provided me with a solution yet and I have been stuck for the best part of a week.

Comment: You `Ticket` methods should be in a separate `TicketController` with `Create(int id)` and `[HttpPost]Create(Ticket model)` methods. and you only need pass the eventID to the method using `return RedirectToAction("Create", "Ticket", new { id = @event.EventID });` - using `Session` is unnecessary. And if its returning the view, its almost certainly because `ModelState` is invalid - debug your code!

Comment: what does your `SaveTickets` view code look like?

Comment: Thanks for your help @StephenMuecke that makes sense needing a separate controller.

Comment: @JamieD77 I've updated my original post to include the saveTickets view

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that you're not telling your `<form>` where to post the data.

When you just use `@using (Html.BeginForm())` it assumes you want to post the data back to the same url that the view came from, or what's in the address bar.

Since the action that returns the view is `SaveTickets` then the data will be posted to `http://host/Events1/SaveTickets`  but your `[HttpPost]` action is `AddToTickets`.

You can either rename your `[HttpPost]` action to `SaveTickets` as well, which would be easiest, or tell your form what the url/action is that you want to post to.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToTickets","Events1"))
```

This might solve the problem, but you want to take Stephen's advice and create a seperate controller for Tickets..